# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED with YouTube video in <iframe>

Tags: html, video, iframe, embedded-resource

I have simple embedded `<iframe>` taken from YouTube:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Multimedia</title>
</head>

<body>

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/33lKUK-SxzQ"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

The video poster is displayed but when I play the video, I get `Video unavailable` error.

Following messages are logged in console in Opera:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

> GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

In Chrome nothing is logged in console but I still cannot play the video.

In Network tab, I can see all resources are loaded with code 200, and one `text/html` resources with code 204.

What's wrong?